# Total variation measure has finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

1. Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $(X, \mathcal{A})$, where $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. It is a well-known fact that $|\mu|(X) < \infty$.
   On the other hand, given a positive measure $\rho$ on $(X, \mathcal{A})$, we may allow $\rho(X) = \infty$. If $\rho$ is a positive measure, then it is also a complex measure. Since $\rho$ is also a complex measure, $|\rho|(X) < \infty$. By positivity of $\rho$, $|\rho| = \rho$, so $\rho(X) < \infty$.

What went wrong, and what's the difference? Why is the infinity allowed on $\rho$ while it is not allowed on $|\mu|$? (I am aware of the proof where $|\mu(X)| < \infty$. A more intuitive explanation, if there is one, would be greatly appreciated.)

2. Let $\rho$ be a positive measure and $\lambda$ be a complex measure $\lambda << \rho$. Let $E \in \mathcal A$ with $\rho(E) = 0$. Then for every $A \subset E \in \mathcal A$, $|\lambda|(A) = 0$?

Attempt for 2: Take a partition of $A = \sqcup A_n$ such that $|\lambda|(A) < \sum_n |\lambda(A_n)| + \epsilon$. Since $A_n \subset E$, $\rho(A_n) = 0$. Hence, $\lambda(A_n) = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$. This shows that $\sum_n |\lambda(A_n| + \epsilon = \epsilon$. Hence, $|\lambda|(A) < \epsilon$. This verifies that $|\lambda|(A) = 0$.

Comment: For $1$, the reason is that we can do additions in $[0,+\infty]$ but not in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ once you add infinities. You could make sense of a (signed) real measure which is bounded from below but not from above and would therefore take values in $\mathbb R\cup \{+\infty\}$. I am not sure about $2$, so this is not a complete answer.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is not a complex measure in the sense that $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty$. Any finite positive measure is a complex measure.  One can still talk about variation measure. The function $\mu(A)=\int_A dx- \int_Ae^{x^2}\,dx$ has local finite variation (it is a Radon measure) but it is not a sign measure $\mu(\mathbb{R})$ is not defined.  $\nu(A)=\int_A\,dx -\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$ is a sign measure $\nu(\mathbb{R})$ is well defined (as $\infty$).

Comment: For any complex measure $\mu$ and a (positive) (or signed-measure or even a Radon measure), and a positive measure $\lambda$,  $\mu\ll\lambda$ means that the variation measure satisfies $|\mu|\ll \lambda$

Comment: No, a positive measure is _not_ a complex measure, because $\infty\notin\Bbb C$. (A _finite_ positive measure is a complex measure, but that doesn't lead to the problem that concerns you.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What about 2?